# Make error trying to build kitti_to_rosbag

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use https://github.com/ethz-asl/kitti_to_rosbag/tree/master/kitti_to_rosbag as a package to convert the kitti dataset to rosbag, which can be further used with Autoware for object detection. I have installed all the dependencies mentioned in the package.xml of kitti_to_rosbag. However I get the error when I use catkin_make in the workspace  :

```
[ 50%] Completed 'glog_src'   
[ 50%] Built target glog_src  
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed  
make: *** [all] Error 2  
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

Being a beginner in ROS and having a deadline for this task, I am not able to figure out how to rectify this. Any and all help is appreciated

system : Ubuntu 16.04
ROS  : Kinetic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264355/make-error-trying-to-build-kitti_to_rosbag/) by [amsks](https://answers.ros.org/users/30843/amsks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-06-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-21**:
The real error is most likely somewhere earlier in your console. Without that it's going to be really difficult to help you.

**Comment by [Cheema](https://answers.ros.org/users/30898/cheema/) on 2017-06-26**:
I have exactly the same question, however can you please elaborate how and where did you install the dependencies?  Find my complete question at http://answers.ros.org/question/264817/i-ran-into-dependency-problem-with-building-catkin_ws-for-kitti_to_rosbag-package/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I have installed all the dependencies mentioned in the package.xml of kitti_to_rosbag

I would still recommend you run:

```
rosdep update
rosdep check --from-paths /path/to/your/catkin_ws/src --ignore-src
```

if anything is missing, run the same command, but replace `check` with `install`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amsks](https://answers.ros.org/users/30843/amsks/) on 2017-06-21**:
I just did it and everything built fine. I think they needed to be updated. Thanks a lot !